# In Indonesia, has insurance company ever win defamation suit?

Tags: insurance

Many insurance company are pretty scammy. When customers get burned they simply blame the agents. That happens even though they know what their agents are doing.

Are there any insurance company that successfully sue customers crying fraud in public.

Comment: Why don't you include some specific cases? What does defamation mean? Don't you think your question is too broad or unclear?

Comment: Can you even find a case of an insurance company *beginning* to sue a customer for defamation in Indonesia?

Comment: I have heard cases that they threatened to sue. Actual lawsuits I haven't seen. In indonesia, defamation means you said something that defame a person and another person feel that they incure loss